# getElementById value doesn't work and I have no idea why (PHP ? Modal ?)

Tags: javascript, php, html

IMPORTANT : **ABOVE SNIPPET DOES WORK** !

Hey guys,

I don't know why but this basic verification that input is not empty don't work  :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title" value="<?= $title ?>" onblur="submit_basic_info()">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="interpreter" name="interpreter" placeholder="Interpret" value="<?= $interpreter ?>" onblur="submit_basic_info()">

<button type="submit" id="submit_info_button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    
<script>
function submit_basic_info() {
                                
    var get_title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    var get_interpreter = document.getElementById("interpreter").value;

    console.log(get_title);
    console.log(get_interpreter);

    if (get_title === "" || get_interpreter === "" ) {

        console.log('if');

        document.getElementById("submit_basic_info").innerHTML = "Please Fill-In every input";
        document.getElementById('submit_info_button').disabled = true;

    } else {

        console.log('else');

        document.getElementById("submit_basic_info").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('submit_info_button').disabled = false;

    }
}
</script>
```

I can see that here in the snippet it work... but why doesn't it in my web page ? Because value is a PHP value ? Because form is inside a modal ?

I've been stuck on this for hours and I can't find any solution...

Help appreciated... :)

```js
function submit_basic_info() {

  var get_title = document.getElementById("title").value;
  var get_interpreter = document.getElementById("interpreter").value;

  console.log(get_title);
  console.log(get_interpreter);

  if (get_title === "" || get_interpreter === "") {

    console.log('if');

    document.getElementById("submit_basic_info").innerHTML = "Please Fill-In every input";
    document.getElementById('submit_info_button').disabled = true;

  } else {

    console.log('else');

    document.getElementById("submit_basic_info").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('submit_info_button').disabled = false;

  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title" value="" onblur="submit_basic_info()">


<input type="text" class="form-control" id="interpreter" name="interpreter" placeholder="Interpret" value="" onblur="submit_basic_info()">

<span id="submit_basic_info">

                                </span>
<button type="submit" id="submit_info_button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Do you get errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: PHP is just filling in the default values. It should still work after the user enters something.

Comment: No error in JavaScript. But it doesn't get the new value entered. It keeps the $title value

Comment: Are you using the submit button? That will submit the form and reload the default values.

Comment: No i'm just using the onblur. But there is no reason for my code not to work.

Comment: You're right, there isn't, so there must be more than what you've posted here. Can you provide a link to the site that fails?